# luatex85: New definition of \pdfcreationdate is problematic

Tags: luatex

The package "datetime2" scanned the macro \pdfcreationdate. This failed with the changed definition in "luatex85.sty" and LuaTeX 0.95. See the following example:

```
\listfiles
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{100}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
%\edef\pdfcreationdate{\pdfcreationdate}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\begin{document}
  \DTMnow
\end{document}
```

After uncommenting the edef line the problem is solved.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

It's a tough problem, unfortunately. The developers of LuaTeX decided to remove several primitives favoring a syntax

```
\pdffeedback <keyword>
```

Some of the removed primitives were expandable:

```
\pdftexrevision
\pdfxformname
\pdfcreationdate
\pdffontname
\pdffontobjnum
\pdffontsize
\pdfpageref
\pdfcolorstackinit
```

which means that *one* expansion step was sufficient for them to deliver their expansion. Note that one expansion step is sufficient also now provided

```
\pdffeedback creationdate
```

is used. The `luatex85` package provides the old names around the new syntax, doing

```
\def\pdfcreationdate{\pdffeedback creationdate}
```

but this means that *two* expansion steps are needed and this is where `datetime2` fails because it does

```
\expandafter\@dtm@parsepdfdatetime\pdfcreationdate\@dtm@endparsepdfdatetime
```

The workaround you use is good, in the particular case, because `\pdfcreationdate` in `pdftex` is “fixed” and doesn't change once set. So `luatex85` *might* indeed do `\edef\pdfcreationdate{\pdffeedback creationdate}`. However this wouldn't work with other old primitives such as `\pdffontsize`, because this requires an argument (a font specifier).

The packages using those primitives should be updated to do two expansion steps or branch their code. For `datetime2` the code

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@dtm@parsepdfdatetime\pdfcreationdate\@dtm@endparsepdfdatetime
```

would work with legacy `pdftex` or LuaTeX 0.85 or later. In the case of `pdftex` or older LuaTeX, the second expansion step would try expanding `D`, so do nothing. In case of LuaTeX 0.85 or later (with `luatex85` loaded) the double expansion would deliver the expected string.

More safely:

```
\ifdefined\pdffeedback
  \expandafter\@dtm@parsepdfdatetime
    \pdffeedback creationdate \@dtm@endparsepdfdatetime
\else
  \expandafter\@dtm@parsepdfdatetime
    \pdfcreationdate\@dtm@endparsepdfdatetime
\fi
```

However, another branching is needed in another part of `datetime2` to make it independent of `luatex85`, where a check about the existence of `\pdfcreationdate` is performed.

Comment: Tricky one: Hans has this down as `\def` not `\edef` in the manual, so presumably we can't rely on expandability (as you note, in general that may not be the case for `\pdffeedback`).

Comment: I understand the reason. But wouldn't it be more appropriate to use \edef in all cases where the emulated macros are “fixed”? It would prohibit some trouble with old code.

Comment: @rolfn I guess it would.

Answer (score 6):

This is fixed in `datetime2` v1.5.1 (2016-06-05). I fixed it by defining a new command `\dtm@pdfcreationdate`:

```
\ifdef\pdfcreationdate
{%
  \edef\dtm@pdfcreationdate{\pdfcreationdate}%
}%
{%
  \ifdef\pdffeedback
  {%
     \edef\dtm@pdfcreationdate{\pdffeedback creationdate}%
  }%
  {}%
}
```

and then using `\dtm@pdfcreationdate` where I'd previously used `\pdfcreationdate`. This approach has the following advantages:

- It doesn't modify `\pdfcreationdate`.
- It allows for any potential future change to the definition of `\pdfcreationdate` that might required deeper expansion.¹
- It works for new versions of LuaLaTeX where the user has chosen not to load `luatex85` (or loads it after `datetime2`).

(XeLaTeX, which doesn't provide `\pdfcreationdate`, still triggers the fallback mode that computes the current time from `\time`, which lacks seconds and time zone.)

---

¹ I don't expect that to happen but, then again, I didn't expect LuaTeX to drop `\pdfcreationdate`.